# replace/redirect in .htaccess using regular expressions

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have transfered my site from joomla to wordpress. Most of the old links have been redirected just fine, but I am getting some weird 404s

What I would like is to be able to redirect this:

http://www.pcsteps.gr/component/content/article?id=575:how-to-guide-wireless-network-security

To this: http://www.pcsteps.gr/575-how-to-guide-wireless-network-security

This is the code I have been using inside the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^component/content/(.+)$ pcsteps.gr/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code removes the /component/content/ part of the URL, but I am left with "article?id=575:how-to-guide-wireless-network-security"

How can I change the code to also remove the "article?id=", keeping the number and replacing the ":" with "-"?

Comment: What did you try that successfully removed "/component/content/" and why won't it remove the rest?

Comment: RewriteRule ^component/content/(.+)$ http://www.pcsteps.gr/$1 [R=301,L] would remove them, but I would be left with the "article?id=575:how-to-guide-wireless-network-security"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=([0-9]+):([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^component/content/article/?$ /%1-%2? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work.

Comment: I missed `article` part. Fixed it now, can you please try.

Comment: Now it removes the component/content/article and the id=, but it doesn't replace the : with a -

I get http://www.pcsteps.gr/575:how-to-guide-wireless-network-security

Comment: ok further update in my answer. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Would it be fine if I made the Rule RewriteRule (.*)/?$ /%1-%2? [L,NC,R=301], so it would change other combinations of the same type?

Comment: Yes you can simply use: `RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2? [L,NC,R=301]`